# Why after downloading my web file offline I need to add index.php?

Tags: codeigniter

I wonder what is the difference between my page offline and online?

After downloading my page offline I need to add (index.php) after my folder file in order to make it viewable?

http://localhost/gsaconst/index.php/articles/news

my online page would be

http://www.gsa-constructionspecialist.com/articles/news

How to delete the index.php in the offline page and still make it viewable not error message like:

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add .htaccess file in offline directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and also make sure you remove index.php from config file 
`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`
find config file **application/config/config.php**